# Android Custom Title Bar views not aligning correctly

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a custom title bar. Here's the style part.

```
<style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
    <item name="android:background">#323331</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">35dip</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0px</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/gradient</item>
</style>
```

Here's the XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#323331"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/satellite" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="right">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/satellite" />

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the class for that XML

```
public class CustomTitle extends Activity {
protected TextView title;
protected ImageView icon;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.customtitle);

    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    icon  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);

    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.customtitle);

}
```

Here's how it appears:

http://imgur.com/0y5SANf

My problem is that those two `imageviews`(satellites) should be aligned to the Left and to the Right. I can't seem to get that to happen.

Does anyone have an idea as to why they aren't aligning?

It appears correctly in the graphical layout in `Eclipse`, but when I run it in the emulator and on my physical device it shows up like the picture. I should mention my activites extend CustomTitle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the layout_weight from your image view and linearlayout. Also use gravity and not layout_gravity. I think (I don't currently have my PC on) this should solve your problem. Another route you could use is to use a relative layout as the root layout instead of your first linearlayout and use alignParentLeft and alignParentRight on your image view and second linearlayout.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with the Linear Layout, the realtive layout worked though, Thanks.